# confused about pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I just started learning c++ (I'm more of a java developer right now) and am having some confusion with using pointers... for example, the following code works

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int * y;
    y = &x; //note this line of code
    *y = 10;
}
```

whereas this code does not work

```
int main() {
     int x = 5;
     int * y;
     y = x;
     *y = 10;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why getting the value "location" using `y = &x` works but as soon as I replace it with `y = x` it causes an error. If anyone knows of a good explanation on pointers please share the link :)

Thank you!

Comment: Pointers store addresses. `x` is an integer. `&x` is an address.

Comment: y is a pointer and you are setting it to an `int`.  This is technically legal, but dereferencing that pointer will cause havok since there isn't definitely a memory location at `"10"`

Comment: I see... this will take some time to get used to fully, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @zero298, Not legal in C++ without being extra persuasive.

Comment: I have a vague and distant memory of the time that pointers were confusing to me. It is long gone.

Comment: @sftrabbit, Same here. I don't understand how I was such an idiot with them, but I know I was. Maybe not as distant, though, since I only started programming and C++ a few years ago.

Comment: @chris By distant I only mean a few years ago! Well I did my first C++ programming about 8 years ago, but I only started to learn it properly 3 years ago. Feels distant, anyway. I'm sure there are old-timers here for which it is a forgotten memory.

Comment: It might be useful to think of addresses as indices into an array, that array being the system's memory. Arrays are common in Java, so maybe that analogy will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see how this works with pointers.

```
int x = 5;
```

You're assigning the value 5 to x which is an int.

```
int *y;
```

You're declaring a pointer to an int.

```
y = &x;
```

Now, the address stored in y is the same as the address of x.

But, if you do this : `y = x`, you're assigning an integer (5 in that case) to a variable that holds *addresses* of integers.

Finally, you have to remember that :

- `&` is the address-of operator, and can be read as "address of"
- `*` is the indirection operator, and can be read as "value pointed to by"

[Tutorial about pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: "Now, the address of y is the same as the address of x." - You're using "the address of `y`" to mean the address stored in `y`. Quite confusing.

Comment: Also, I know you took this from cplusplus.com (another example of it having misleading information), but `&` is better called the address-of operator and `*` the indirection operator. The terminology you and they have used can easily be confused with terminology for reference types.

Comment: @sftrabbit address-of makes sense, but can you explain what's meant by indirection? Why is it called that?

Comment: "you're assigning an integer ... to the address of y which is not defined" - This needs to be reworded. It's not assigning an integer to the address of y, it's assigning an integer to y when y expects the *address* of an integer.

Comment: @Trojan It's a term that comes from assembly (as far as I'm aware). When you do `*p`, you are accessing the object that `p` points to *indirectly*. So you are *performing indirection*. That is the terminology that is being adopted by the standard.

Comment: Also +1 for not using the terminology "reference" for `&`.

Comment: A lot of comment here :). Thanks for the correction @sftrabbit.

Answer (score 0):

`y` is a pointer to an `int`. `x` **is** an `int`.  Therefore whenever you set `y=x` you are telling `y` that whenever it gets dereferenced, it should go looking at memory location `10` (or whatever `x` is at assignment time).  And there probably isn't a memory allocation at `10`.  Or at least not what you are expecting.  If you want to get the location of `x`, get a pointer to it with `&x`.

```
int main() {
     int x = 5;
     int * y;
     y = &x; // <-- NOTE THE "&" WHICH MEANS GET REFERENCE
     *y = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a pointer is a variable that holds a memory location.  In your instance, the variable "x" holds the value 5, where the variable y holds a location in memory. the "&" operator will enable you to use the location in memory of the "x" variable

```
cout >> x; //will give you an output of 5.
cout >> &x; //will give you an output of the memory location of the variable x.

y = &x;
cout >> y; //will give you an output of the memory location of the variable x.
```